# how to add delete button in each row of my table?

Tags: python, html, django, sql-delete

How is going? I'm learning to programming in django. For the moment I'm building a simple app that utilizing a form update the referenced table.

Now I'm try to add a delete button in each row of my table but, beside I have tried a lot of solutions, I didn't find one that works correctly.

Below my code:

urls

```
from django.urls import path
from app import views

app_name = 'main'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.homepage, name='homepage'),
    path('delete_item/<int:pk>', views.delete_item, name="delete_item"),
]
```

forms

```
from django import forms
from .models import Income

class IncomeModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Income
        fields = "__all__"
```

tables

```
import django_tables2 as tables
from django_tables2.utils import A
from .models import Income

class PersonTable(tables.Table):
    delete = tables.LinkColumn('main:delete_item', args=[A('delete-id')], attrs={'a': {'class': 'btn'}})
    class Meta:
        model = Income
        template_name = "django_tables2/bootstrap.html"
```

views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Income
from .tables import PersonTable
from .forms import IncomeModelForm

def homepage(request):
    table = PersonTable(Income.objects.all())

    if request.method == 'POST':
         form = IncomeModelForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
             print("Il form è valido")
             new_input = form.save()

    else :
        form = IncomeModelForm()

    context= {"form": form,
            "table":table }
    return render(request, "app/base.html", context)


def delete_item(request, pk):

    Income.objects.filter(id=pk).delete()
    items = Income.objects.all()
    context = {
    'items': items
    }
    return render(request, 'app/base.html', context)
```

html

```
{% load static %}
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="it">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <div class="container">
        <form class="" action="" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form|crispy}}
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="INVIA">
        </form>
</div>

<br>
<br>

<div class="container">
    {% render_table table %}
</form>
</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

My table disply the column "Delete" but no buttoms, only a "-". Why? Where is my error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you display the record in a table you need to add an extra tabledata with delete form button. Eg:

```
<table>

{% for item in items%}

<tr>
<td>{{item.id}}</td>
<td>{{item.name}}</td>
<td>
    <form method="delete">
        <input type="hidden" value="{{item.id}}" name="delete-id">
        <input type="Submit">Delete</button>
    </form>
</td>
</tr>

{% endfor}
</table>
```

> Now, in your views.py add DELETE section and delete the record:

```
if request.method == 'DELETE':
        Person.objects.get(pk=request.DELETE['delete-id']).delete()
```

> You are using django_tables2, you can simply add this code in your tables.py

```
from django_tables2.utils import A  # alias for Accessor
class PersonTable(tables.Table):
    delete = tables.LinkColumn('main:delete_item', args=[A('delete-id')], attrs={
    'a': {'class': 'btn'}
    })
```

Comment: check if request.method is DELETE like you are checking for POST

Comment: I have edited the answer, I have changed method to DELETE instead of POST to make it more clear.

Comment: I have adjusted the code following your tips but dosn't work yet :(, I have modified the code of the post above.

Comment: check this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55705666/django-tables2-with-edit-and-delete-buttons-how-to-do-it-properly?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: I have followed the link and adjust the code (and I have updated it in this post) but the table disply the column "Delete" but no buttoms, only a "-". Why? Where is my error?

Comment: Try to overwrite your `django_tables2/bootstrap.html` and add custom delete button as I showed above in the answer.